# Github link only deploying to the readme

Tags: github-pages, webdeploy

https://github.com/AlanKMiller1501/bamazon

As I stated, when I click on the link I go only to the readme and not to the actual page. What simple thing am I messing up?

Comment: Looks like your repo has server-side code. My understanding is that GitHub pages only serves front-end assets. Are you deploying it from other place?

Comment: No, only deployed by me. What does server-side code mean and how do I fox it?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

## Purpose of GitHub Repo

#### 1. A directory or storage space where your projects can live.

At its basis, GitHub is just that: on online hosting place where you can store your source code. While you can work exclusively on your personal laptop, an online repository makes it incredibly easier to share the code with others and collaborate without hassle.

#### 2. A static file hosting via GitHub Pages.

As an added bonus, each GitHub Repo can function as a static web page server. That is, if your repo consists of simple `HTML/CSS/JS` files, you won't need a paid hosting to put the pages live. It also natively supports `Jekyll`, making it a great option for personal blog or the likes.

However, if your code requires a server—e.g. running a database, calling cloud functions, etc—GitHub won't deploy your projects; only store them. Depending on your actual needs, you might want to consider deployment services like Heroku or Firebase, or linux servers like Linode or Digital Ocean.

#### 3. What a visitor sees when viewing a repo

When someone visits `https://github.com/user-name/repo` URL, the following will be shown.

- A summary of the repo,
- A full list of files, and
- (if present) content of `README.MD`

So, what you're describing in the question is a default behavior. If you want to deploy a project via GitHub Pages—which you can't in this case, as it's a server-side project—the URL should be `https://user-name.github.io/project-title`.

---

## Front- vs Back-end Code

In a nut-shell, code that can run in a browser is considered *front-end* (or *client-side*), and code that only runs on a server is considered *back-end* (or *server-side*).

For example, all `HTML/CSS` files are by definition front-end. Any DOM manipulation via JavaScript (like `document.querySelector` and stuff) is front-end.

---

## TL;DR.

- Your project requires a server. (E.g. `require` syntax, `mysql` access, etc.)
- You can *store* those files at GitHub, but cannot *deploy* them natively via GitHub.
- Nothing to fix here, because nothing's broken.
- If only for testing/practicing, just keep the project running on your `localhost`; otherwise find a server hosting solution.

Comment: This is an amazing answer. Thank you so much.